# Замена GOM Player

Tags: видео, поиск-программ

Пользовался GOM Player'ом, но последнее время перестал устраивать, т. к.

1. Не воспроизводит некоторые кодеки (как минимум, h265)
2. Может переставать менять картинку после перемотки или при повторном воспроизведении файла (причём, даже на файлах, с которыми несколько лет назад работал нормально)
3. Раз в сутки при закрытии запускает браузер с рекламной страницей

**Хочу либо исправить пункты 1 и 2, либо поменять его на другой плеер, устраивающий по характеристикам (но пока такого не нашёл).**

Требования к воспроизведению:

- Управление скоростью воспроизведения с максимумом не менее x4 и шагом не более .1 с помощью кнопок, желательно <kbd>z</kbd> (сбросить до 1), <kbd>x</kbd> (уменьшить на .1) и <kbd>с</kbd> (увеличить на .1)
- Перемотка стрелками влево/вправо по 10 секунд, более быстрая перемотка с добавлением клавиш-модификаторов
- Выбор проигрываемой аудиодорожки из меню, вызываемого по шоткату, например, <kbd>a</kbd>
- AB-повтор (зацикленное воспроизведение фрагмента видео) и его отмена по шоткатам, желательно <kbd>[</kbd> (установить начало), <kbd>]</kbd> (установить конец), <kbd>\</kbd> (отменить)

Желательные требования:

- Копирование и/или сохранение текущего кадра (GOM вместо текущего берёт следующий ключевой)
- Покадровое листание видео в обе стороны (нет в GOM)
- Масштабирование и сдвига видео цифровой клавиатурой
- Возможность поворота и переворота видео при воспроизведении
- Возможность регулировки яркости, контрастности и других подобных параметров при воспроизведении

Требования к общему поведению плеера:

- Размер окна должен НЕ меняться при смене проигрываемого файла
- Наличие режимов окна: обычное, поверх всех окон и поверх всех окон во время воспроизведения с возможностью их переключения нажатием шоткатов, а не через настройки
- Перетаскивание окна за всю площадь, желательно с умением притягиваться к границам других окон
- Возможность менять размер окна цифрами <kbd>1</kbd> (50%), <kbd>2</kbd> (200%), <kbd>3</kbd> (150%), <kbd>4</kbd> (200%) или аналогичная функциональность
- Открытие файл перетаскиванием на окно
- Возможность зациклить плейлист, желательно ещё возможность зациклить конкретное видео в плейлисте
- Возможность выставить воспроизведение в рандомном порядке
- Умение воспроизводить аудио-файлы

Не имеет значения:

- Сохранение позиции в проигрываемом файле

Comment: VLC смотрел?...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, смотрю в нём те файлы, которые gom не открывает. Но как-то ничего из перечисленного там не замечал. Или плохо искал?

Comment: Ох сколько требований, но мало кто использует кучу плейеров чтобы знать их особенности. И даже если один плейер, то половину из ваших требований не использовать. А так - PotPlayer

Comment: @vitidev, ну я пользуюсь перечисленным :) А что PotPlayer умеет?

Comment: 80% из того что описано в списке и умеет так или иначе. Это из того что я потыкал. . Даже хоткеи совпадают. Если бы не было написано GOM, я бы подумал что пишут про Pot. Умеет ли "как надо" - слишком глубоко копать. Больно много настроек, в которых сложно ориентироваться.

Comment: @vitidev, поставил, сейчас буду смотреть. Но кажется, у него с проверкой обновлений проблемы: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahHVB.png.

Comment: С этим не знаю. Я оригинал не ставил никогда. Я использую локализованные сборки, которые не вижу смысла обновлять ибо не использую и 5% возможностей. Только когда ютуб ломается. Но выбирать сборки это уже на руборд вам.

Comment: @vitidev, да, очень похоже, даже интерфейс и хоткеи почти те же. Перемотка 6 вместо 10 - может и настраивается, но пока думаю, что пойдёт. Цифровая клавиатура работает иначе - растягивание вместо сдвига. Рандомный порядок в плейлисте не вижу. Но самое критичное - размер окна меняется автоматически при смене видео - сейчас настройки порою, но очень сомневаюсь, что они такое вынесли.

Comment: Рэндомный - пкм в плейлисте и там сортировка. Размер - настройки...воспроизведение...размер окна...не менять (надеюсь это оно)

Comment: @vitidev, почти. Там рядом флажок "Одна смена размера при запуске" - вот оно. Давай ответом его. Вроде хорошо смотрится.

Comment: Сдвига нет - а вы контрол зажмите и будет вам сдвиг. А насчет ответа - я считаю что такие вопросы не подходят для so, а больше для руборда "ищу софт" и лучше бы удалить его после

Comment: @vitidev, вполне могут подходить: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под этот список подходит PotPlayer. 90% требований он умеет. Имеет огромное количество настроек и скинов. Может работать с внешними кодеками вроде K-Lite на случай проблем со встроенными.

Также имеет сборки с прикрученной возможностью просмотра youtube, torrent и подъем частоты кадров до 60к/с...и другие расширения.